# .NET: LINQ Not Filtering For Null Values

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, propertyinfo

I'm getting a NULL reference exception for code that runs after I attempted to filter out null values for a list of `_PropertInfo` objects using LINQ.

The error occurs in the foreach loop of the CheckAutoPatientLookupProperties method.

The exact exception read:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in InterfacePatientAutoMatch.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

```
AutoPatientLookup APIParameters = new AutoPatientLookup();

//to be used only for testing
APIParameters = InitializeTestPatientInfo();
CheckAutoPatientLookupProperties(APIParameters);

public static AutoPatientLookup InitializeTestPatientInfo(bool SSN = false, bool PatientNumber = false, bool Gender = false)
{
    AutoPatientLookup TestAPIParameters = new AutoPatientLookup();
    TestAPIParameters.FirstName = "First";
    TestAPIParameters.LastName = "Last";
    TestAPIParameters.DOB = "4/9/1953";
    if (SSN)
    {
        TestAPIParameters.SSN = 00000000;
    }
    if (PatientNumber)
    {
        TestAPIParameters.PatientNumber = 000;
    }
    if (Gender)
    {
        TestAPIParameters.Gender = "F";
    }

    return TestAPIParameters;
}

public static void CheckAutoPatientLookupProperties(AutoPatientLookup TestObj)
{

    foreach (_PropertyInfo Property in TestObj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(Property => Property != null))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AutoPatientLookup Instance Property {0} = {1}", Property.Name, Property.GetValue(TestObj,null).ToString());
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public class AutoPatientLookup
{
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int PatientNumber { get; set; }
    public int SSN { get; set; }
}
```

By hovering over `Property.GetValue(TestObj,null)` while debugging I found it to be null when the method looped over the Gender property, which isn't initialized in the `InitializeTestPatientInfo` method.

Is there something wrong with my LINQ expression when outlining my foreach loop? Shouldn't it have skipped to Gender property? I don't get any compile time errors so I think my expression is legal, but it's not being honored.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If it is coming from database try DB.null.

Comment: `TestObj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(Property => Property != null)` isn't filtering properties where their values are null... it's filtering PropertyInfo objects against being null.

Comment: @john If you're comment were an answer I would mark it as right